# Show that $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $u$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $u$ be a root of $f=x^3-x^2+x+2\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $K=\mathbb{Q}(u)$. Prove that $f=m_\mathbb{Q}(u)$.

I have no idea how to approach this problem. Should I prove that $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$? If so, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Yes, that's a good plan. Hint: all rational zeros of $f$ are integers.

Comment: Since your polynomial is small, you can also attempt to do this via brute force: write $f=(ax^2+bx+c)(dx+e)$, and try to derive some contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is monic (and the minimal polynomial of $u$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is the unique *monic* irreducible polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ having $u$ as a root in $K$), it suffices to show that $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ as you observed. The rational root theorem dictates that the only possible rational roots of $f$ are $\pm 1, \pm 2$ - you can check that none of these are zeros of $f$. Since $f$ has degree 3, this is enough to prove that $f$ is irreducible.

Comment: It suffices to show that $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ you mean?

Comment: @Seven: hopefully this edit clears up the intent of the remark "$f$ is monic" - thanks for your comment.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I dropped the last comment rather hastily assuming that you'd appeal to some irreducibility criterion over $\Bbb Z$, and were establishing that fact in the first line of your answer.